# Anylogic, animating a queue

Tags: animation, queue, anylogic

This always annoys me so I usually just ignore it but this time it has prompted me to ask the question...

I am animating agents queuing for a resource using a path to represent the queue.  I have a moveTo block to move my agents to a node which is placed at the front of the queue.  When the queue is empty and an agent arrives to be serviced, it looks great as the agent moves to the end of the queue path and smoothly progresses along the path to the front of the queue where the node is located.
However, if there are multiple agents in the queue then new agents will move to the queue path and move all the way to the front of the queue (where the node is located) and then jump back to their correct position on the queue path.

If I put the node at the back end of the queue then the animation looks great when the agents arrive as they join the queue behind others already there but when the agent at the front of the queue seizes the resource they are waiting for it jumps to the back of the queue and then proceeds along the queue to the resource node.

Any ideas on how to get this to animate correctly?

Comment: Play with the "restore agent location on exit" property in the queue and moveto blocks (try all combinations). Should help. Maybe change it dynamically based on the situation, i.e. queue size

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this simply using a Conveyor block to represent the 'shuffling along' queue (with some specific configuration), but it's worth considering the wider picture (which also helps understand why trying to add a MoveTo block to a Service with its queue along a path cannot achieve what you want).

A process model *can* include model-relevant spatiality where movement times are important. (As well as the MoveTo block, blocks such as RackPick/Store and Service blocks with "Send seized resources" checked implicitly include movement.) However, typically you don't: a Service block with the queue being along a path is using the path *just* to provide some visual representation of the queue. In the underlying model agents arrive instantly into the queue from the upstream block and instantly enter the delay when a resource is free — that is the process abstraction of the model. Hence trying to 'fix the animation' with a previous MoveTo block or similar will not work because the Service block is not *supposed* to be representing such a conception of its queue (so agents will 'spring back' to the reality of the underlying behaviour as you observed). Additionally, a 'properly animated queue' would be obscuring the underlying basis of the model (making it seem as if that movement is being explicitly modelled when it isn't).

A Conveyor does conceptually capture agents which have to stay a certain distance apart and (for an accumulating conveyor) explicitly models agents moving along when there is free space. So, although it may seem counterintuitive, this is actually a 'correct' detailed conceptualisation of a moving human queue (which also of course matches an actual conveyor).

To make it work as you want it, you need to make the size of the agents (just from the conveyor's perspective) such that you only have the required number of people in your queue (now a conveyor), with the following Service block just having a capacity 1 queue (which thus represents the 'front of the queue person' only) — Service blocks can't have a capacity 0 queue. You can use a Point Node as the location for this single-entry queue which is just beyond the end of the conveyor path (so that this effectively represents the first position in the queue) — see below.

[image: Example conveyor-based process flow]

You then want the agent length on the conveyor to represent your 'queue slot length' which requires specifying the queue capacity (a variable in my example), so something like

`path.length(METER) / (queueCapacity - 1)`

where `path` is your conveyor path. (The conveyor represents all queue 'slots' except the first, hence why we subtract 1 above.)

You could also encapsulate all of this as a custom ServiceWithMovingQueue block or similar.

Note that the Queue before the Conveyor is needed in case the conveyor has no room for an arriving agent (i.e., the 'conceptual queue' is full). If you wanted to be particularly realistic you'd have to decide what happens in real-life and explicitly model that (e.g., overflow queue, agent leaves, etc.).

P.S. Another alternative is to use the Pedestrian library, where Service with Lines space markup is designed to model this: partial example flow below. However, that means switching your agents to be pedestrians (participating in the pedestrian modelling underlying physics model for movement) and back again which is performance-intensive (and can cause some bizarre movement in some cases due to the physics). Plus, because the pedestrian library has no explicit concept of resources for pedestrian services, you'd have to do something like have resource pool capacity changes influence which service points were open or not. (The service points within a Service with Lines markup have functions like `setSuspended` so you can dynamically set them as 'open' or 'closed', in this case linked to whether resources are on-shift to man them.)

[image: Example pedestrian-library-based process flow]

P.P.S. Note that, from a modelling accuracy perspective, capturing the 'real' movement in a human queue is typically irrelevant because

- If the queue's empty, the time to move from the end to the front is typically negligible compared to the service time (and, even if it's not negligible, a service which generally has a queue present means this extra movement is only relevant for a tiny proportion of arrivals  — see below).
- If the queue's not empty, people move up whilst others are being served so there is no delay in terms of the service (which can always accept the next person 'immediately' after finishing with someone because they are already at the front of the queue).

Comment: Thanks @StuartRossiter I will give the conveyor suggestion a go next time.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be fixed with the existing blocks of the process modeling library.

Nevertheless, if you use the pedestrian library, this problem doesn't occur, maybe you can consider using it if the animation is that important, at the cost of processing speed of your model

The only other way to actually do it, is by creating your own Agent-Based model to handle the behavior of agents in a queue, but this is not very straight forward.

Now, if you think about operation time, there is no difference for the process statistics if an agent moves like it does or if it moves to the end of the line, so in terms of results, you shouldn't be worried about it

Comment: I am sure it is possible by setting animations invisible temporarily, though, no? (not saying it is easy but surely possible?)

Comment: To do it, you need to first identify the last person in the queue and use the moveTo towards a point just behind that person, but that place changes constantly, so you would need to predict the length of the queue at the time the agent arrives to it... so it's basically impossible without detecting obstacles... but you can try to prove me wrong as an exercise... I tried to do this in the past and decided it was a futile effort.

Comment: Thanks gent's, in the past I have just let it slide but this time it was annoying me so thought I'd ask the question.  I'm using a seize block so some of the queuing options are not exposed but even then restoring an agent to it's original position is exactly what the queue does now which is why it animates incorrectly.  
Felipe, unfortunately speed is important so jumping into pedestrian blocks is out of the question - but thanks for the suggestion.
Ultimately it doesn't concern me too much but it would be nice to not have to explain the bizarre movements each time you show it to a client.